# jquery uncaught TypeError cannot read property 'left' of undefined on first page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

good day,

im having a problem in my website im getting "uncaught  TypeError  cannot read property 'left' of undefined" in my homepage but everythings fine in others pages.

hope anyone will help me with this. thanks,

script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cssmenu').prepend('<div id="indicatorContainer"><div id="pIndicator"><div id="cIndicator"></div></div></div>');
    var activeElement = $('#cssmenu>ul>li:first');

    $('#cssmenu>ul>li').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            activeElement = $(this);
        }
    });
    var posLeft = activeElement.position().left; //here i get the error
});
```

html:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
   <li><a class="active" style="font-family: Calibri;" href='Home.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a style="font-family: Calibri;" href='AboutUs.html'><span>About Us</span></a></li>
   <li class='active has-sub'>
      <a style="font-family: Calibri;" href='Products.html'><span>
      Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a style="font-family: Calibri;" href='Products_Argus_Responder.html'><span>Argus
            Responder</span></a>
         </li>
         <li><a style="font-family: Calibri;" href='Products_Argus_Explorer.html'><span>Argus
            Explorer</span></a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a style="font-family: Calibri;" href='Warranty.html'><span>Warranty</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a style="font-family: Calibri;" href='ContactUs.html'><span>Contact
      Us</span></a>
   </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no `<ul>` start tag. Change it and it will work

Comment: You are missing `<ul>` inside `<div id='cssmenu'>`

Comment: Is that all on the html part?

Comment: Works fine **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/rkmvx94L/)** if you add `<ul>`

Comment: Please tidy up an indent your html code. There are missing opening tags (div and ul). It is obvious that the code will generate an error if there is no element with the id `cssmenu` which is called in your JavaScript file.

Comment: @Vincent Gumera why don't you pick an answer? didn't any of the answers help you?

Comment: sorry for the late reply guys.. thanks for the responses here. project that im working is already done. thanks for the resources. thank you all :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `<ul>` inside the `#cssmenu` so your selector `#cssmenu>ul>li.active` won't find any element as it looks for a `ul` which is a child of `#cssmenu` element.

Also you can simplify your jQuery as below using class selector

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cssmenu').prepend('<div id="indicatorContainer"><div id="pIndicator"><div id="cIndicator"></div></div></div>');
  var activeElement = $('#cssmenu>ul>li.active');
  if (activeElement.length == 0) {
    activeElement = $('#cssmenu>ul>li:first');
  }
  var posLeft = activeElement.position().left; //here i get the error
  console.log(posLeft)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" style="font-family: Calibri;" href='Home.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a style="font-family: Calibri;" href='AboutUs.html'><span>About Us</span></a></li>
    <li class='active has-sub'>
      <a style="font-family: Calibri;" href='Products.html'><span>
        Products</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a style="font-family: Calibri;" href='Products_Argus_Responder.html'><span>Argus
          Responder</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a style="font-family: Calibri;" href='Products_Argus_Explorer.html'><span>Argus
          Explorer</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a style="font-family: Calibri;" href='Warranty.html'><span>Warranty</span></a></li>
    <li class='last'><a style="font-family: Calibri;" href='ContactUs.html'><span>Contact
      Us</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sffy82y8/3/), [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sffy82y8/4/)

Answer (score 2):

how about this

```
  $('#cssmenu li:first');
```

this will look for every li tags, then will select first one, this removes the complication of, where the tag is exactly, as long as it's in #cssmenu element

Comment: Please try adding more details on how that answer could provide a solution to the problem instead of just copy-pasting code snippets. That way, the OP (and anybody else) will be able to get a better understanding of your answer.

Comment: does this look better?

Answer (score 0):

This function can't find the "activeElement", because it's selector can't find any  element right after "#cssmenu"
So it's null and you can't call position() on it.